# Motivation for the standard resolution in group cohomology

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

We define the cohomology of a group $G$ as $H^n(G,A)=Ext^n_{\mathbb Z(G)}(\mathbb Z,A)$ for every $G$-module $A$.

To compute it, we use the standard resolution $E_\bullet$ for $\mathbb Z$ (see Lang, Algebra, page 826). But, since the choice of the (projective!) resolution should be ineffective, we could choose another resolution for $\mathbb Z$. Now, what's wrong with $$0\longrightarrow \mathbb Z\longrightarrow \mathbb Z\longrightarrow 0\quad ?$$
This should give the same result, and this seems actually somehow strange to me, so perhaps I have some confusion with definitions.

Thank you in advance for any help to clarify this.

Comment: Why do you believe that the integers form an injective module? Also the Hom-functor is contravariant in the first argument so are you sure an injective resolution is appropriate?

Comment: Good point, thanks. Another question, if I may. In more abstract contexts the definition is given substituting to $\mathbb Z$ the terminal object $1$ of the category. In this case the category is $Mod(G)$ and the terminal object is $0\in Mod(G)$. So if $\Gamma(A)=Hom(1,A)$ then $H^n:=R^n\Gamma(A)$. I see contradiction in this, since we have a resolution for $\mathbb Z$ and not for the terminal object $0$. Moreover, the $0$ resolution should work as a free resolution for $0$, making everything trivial. Again, where am I confused?

Comment: @W.Rether: I bet if you look at the surrounding context, the places where you see $\hom(1, A)$ is meant in a category of sheaves of **sets**. More precisely, it is $\hom(1, uA)$ where $u$ is the forgetful functor from sheaves of abelian groups to sheaves of abelian sets. By the free-forgetful adjunction this is isomorphic to $\hom(F1, A) \cong \hom(\mathbb{Z}, A)$ (now in the category of abelian sheaves), where $\mathbb{Z}$ means the locally constant sheaf.

Comment: Of course! This is actually what I was missing. Thank you very much.

Comment: About the question, you can't use the resolution $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ since it not projective ! Indeed, we are in the category of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules (not $\mathbb{Z}$-modules), so $\mathbb{Z}$ is not necessarily free.